# Grab the innerHTML and insert to input value using many similar class selector

Tags: javascript, html

I have a single `input` as in follows:

```
<input type='text' class='txtwarna' name='txtwarna' value=''/>
```

And, this is HTML with many similar elements, say, `cls`, as:

```
<div class="ct-a">
    <ul class='wr'>
        <li class='cls color1'>Kuning</li>
        <li class='cls color2'>Putih</li>
        <li class='cls color3'>Hijau</li>
        <li class='cls color4'>Biru</li>                          
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="ct-b">
    <ul class='wr'>
        <li class='cls color1'>Biru</li>
        <li class='cls color2'>Hitam</li>
        <li class='cls color3'>Putih</li>
        <li class='cls color4'>Merah</li>
        <li class='cls color5'>Coklat</li>
        <li class='cls color6'>Abu-abu</li>                         
    </ul>
</div>
```

*What I tried* - not working:

```
var strHtml = document.getElementsByClassName("cls");
var valInput = document.getElementsByClassName("txtwarna");
for (var i = 0; i  < strHtml.length; i++) {
    strHtml[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        valInput.value = strHtml.innerHTML; 
});
}
```

Question: How to get each of the innerHTML string, say, biru, putih, kuning, etc when user clicks on it and insert the innerHTML string into single input value?

The value will be changed based on user's click.

Comment: It looks like you actually want a [`select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)

Comment: Wait, I try to write the code using `select` and show it here

Comment: no, not using `select`

Comment: valInput  is an array : Add `[0]`  to get the input element like this: `document.getElementsByClassName("txtwarna")[0];`

Comment: also don't set it to `innerHTML` but `textContent`

Comment: using `document.getElementsByClassName("txtwarna")[0];` and `textContent` give me result: `undefined` as input value :)
fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PaijoPapua/120egnuz/16/

Comment: `valInput.value = strHtml.innerHTML` - `strHtml` is the result of `getElementsByClassName`, a HTMLCollection. That does not have an `innerHTML`.

Comment: Change `strHtml.innerHTML` to `this.innerHTML` in your click handler in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `value` of the `valInput` to overwrite the value.

The clicked element is available through `e.target.innerHTML`

```js
var strHtml = document.getElementsByClassName("cls");
var valInput = document.getElementsByClassName("txtwarna")[0];
var allLi = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

const onLiClick = (e) => {
  valInput.value = e.target.innerHTML;
}

Array.from(allLi).forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', onLiClick));
```

```html
<input type='text' class='txtwarna' name='txtwarna' value=''/> 

<div class="ct-a">
    <ul class='wr'>
        <li class='cls color1'>Kuning</li>
        <li class='cls color2'>Putih</li>
        <li class='cls color3'>Hijau</li>
        <li class='cls color4'>Biru</li>                          
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="ct-b">
    <ul class='wr'>
        <li class='cls color1'>Biru</li>
        <li class='cls color2'>Hitam</li>
        <li class='cls color3'>Putih</li>
        <li class='cls color4'>Merah</li>
        <li class='cls color5'>Coklat</li>
        <li class='cls color6'>Abu-abu</li>                         
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this also works as I wish. so, there are two answers work here (below answer) as I wish . I want to vote up but not enough reputation. okay, noted/saved your answer.

Comment: so without `li` it turns into `undefined` right?

Comment: Well if there are no `li`, there is no evntListener added and `onLiClick` will never be triggered. The input will stay empty.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly do what you are asking by simply adding a `click` listener to the document and setting the `input.value` to match the clicked element's [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent). Here using [`Element.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) to [delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation#:%7E:text=Event%20delegation%20is%20handling%20an,on%20elements%20within%20the%20container.) clicks to the `li` elements with a 'cls' class.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.txtwarna');

document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target.matches('li.cls')) {
    input.value = event.target.textContent;
  }
});
```

```css
ul.wr {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' class='txtwarna' name='txtwarna' value=''/> 

<div class="ct-a">
    <ul class='wr'>
        <li class='cls color1'>Kuning</li>
        <li class='cls color2'>Putih</li>
        <li class='cls color3'>Hijau</li>
        <li class='cls color4'>Biru</li>                          
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="ct-b">
    <ul class='wr'>
        <li class='cls color1'>Biru</li>
        <li class='cls color2'>Hitam</li>
        <li class='cls color3'>Putih</li>
        <li class='cls color4'>Merah</li>
        <li class='cls color5'>Coklat</li>
        <li class='cls color6'>Abu-abu</li>                         
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

However, it seems like you are actually wanting the functionality of a `select` element.

```html
<div class="ct-a">
  <select class='wr'>
    <optgroup label="ct-a">
      <option class='cls color1' value='Kuning'>Kuning</option>
      <option class='cls color2' value='Putih'>Putih</option>
      <option class='cls color3' value='Hijau'>Hijau</option>
      <option class='cls color4' value='Biru'>Biru</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="ct-b">
      <option class='cls color1' value="Biru">Biru</option>
      <option class='cls color2' value="Hitam">Hitam</option>
      <option class='cls color3' value="Putih">Putih</option>
      <option class='cls color4' value="Merah">Merah</option>
      <option class='cls color5' value="Coklat">Coklat</option>
      <option class='cls color6' value="Abuabu">Abuabu</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: not using `select`, please. but, your code above works.

Comment: actually, I must ignore the `ul` and other class selectors for other `calling function`. okay. nice.

Comment: Edited to only delegate to `li.cls` elements

Answer (score 1):

```
var strHtml = document.getElementsByClassName('cls');
var valInput = document.getElementsByClassName('txtwarna');
for (var i = 0; i < strHtml.length; i++) {
  strHtml[i].addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    valInput[0]['value'] = event.currentTarget['innerHTML'];
  });
}
```